# What is this weird, dull looking, gray patching on my beardie's head and neck?

Tags: health, reptiles, skin-condition, bearded-dragon

I noticed this a few days ago, it doesn't look like anything normal, I was wondering if it might be scale rot due to too much moisture, but now it's not so gray anymore, I completely dried and cleaned his habitat just to make sure that was all good, then I gave him a good bath and now his color is back a little bit. But just in case can anybody tell me if something might be wrong with him or if it's just a really slow shed that looks weird?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, it was just a very slow shed that was a little dark in color. I guess he's finally gotten big enough to start having uneven sheds.